# Why isn't the following code printing values run time?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, ubuntu, memory-management

as the cat /proc/meminfo provides dynamic details I want to update the text area system values change. I tried the following.But doesn't work.Please help

```
Thread th=new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
while(true)
{
  try{
       p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/meminfo");
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                 while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                 {
                     textArea.append(s+"\n");
                 }
                 p.waitFor();
                 p.destroy();
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {

      }
 }
});
```

Comment: I replaced testArea.append with System.out.println, and it worked as expected. You may need to elaborate

Comment: But the output is so long that I want to print them line after line.How do I manage it then?

Comment: If the output is too long, consider replacing the contents of 'textArea' with the output, rather than appending. Also, I would limit the speed, with Thread.sleep or similar

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, `textArea` isn't doing anything. To print values in Java, use `System.out.println`.

You can replace:

```
textArea.append(s+"\n");
```

With:

```
System.out.print(s+"\n");
```

Or even easier: `println` automatically appends a new line after your text:

```
System.out.println(s);
```

Another issue is that the `readLine` method could be hanging your program. Step through with a debugger if that's the case.

Comment: But the output is so long that I want to print them line after line.How do I manage it then?

Comment: I mean I want to print in Frame text area. But System.out would only print it in Console